# Ajax function not working for next element played by 'for' in django template

Tags: python, ajax, django, api, django-templates

I meet difficulties as below :

I have a blog page. In blog ,i create 'comment' function to comment post. And comments has 'like' function. For this ,i create two view function ,one of them simple function ,second is api function. And create jquery ajax for to call api function. After api calling ,it update data in db. Problem is :
If i create two comment ,ajax function works only for first comment for to like comment. It looks like ,for first comment CommentLikeAPIToggle works ,for next comments CommentLikeToggle works. Here is my codes :
views.py

```
class CommentLikeToggle(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url( self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs.get('id')
        obj = get_object_or_404(Comment,id=id)
        url_ = obj.content_object.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.likes.all():
                obj.likes.remove(user)
            else:
                obj.likes.add(user)
        return url_

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import authentication, permissions

class CommentLikeAPIToggle(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request,id=None, format=None):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Comment,id=id)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        updated = False
        liked = False
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.likes.all():
                liked = False
                obj.likes.remove(user)
            else:
                liked = True
                obj.likes.add(user)
            updated = True
        data = {
            'updated':updated,
            'liked':liked
               }
        return Response(data)
```

Ajax function :

```
function updateComLike (newCount,btn,verb){
      btn.text("  "+newCount+ " " + verb);
      btn.attr({"data-likes": newCount,"class":"fa fa-thumbs-up"})
}

$("#com-like").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  var this_ = $(this)
  var likeUrl = this_.attr("data-href")
  var likeCount = parseInt(this_.attr("data-likes"))
  $.ajax({
     url: likeUrl,
     method: "GET",
     data : {},
     success: function(data){
        var newLikes;
         if (data.liked){
              newLikes = likeCount + 1
              updateComLike(newLikes,this_ ,gettext("Unlike"))
            } else {
              newLikes = likeCount - 1
              updateComLike(newLikes,this_ ,gettext("Like"))
                 }
       }, error: function(error){
      }
    })
})
```

Template tag :

```
{% for comment in comments %}
{{ comment.content }}
<footer>  
   <a data-href="{{comment.get_api_com_like_url}}" data-likes=" 
  {{comment.likes.count}}" href="{{comment.get_com_like_url}}" id="com-like">
   <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>  {{comment.likes.count}}
     {% if request.user in comment.likes.all %}  {% trans "Unlike" %}
     {%else%}{%trans "Like" %}{% endif %}
   </a>
</footer>
{% endfor %}
```

Urls :

```
url(r'^api/(?P<id>\d+)/com-like/$',CommentLikeAPIToggle.as_view(), name='com-like-api-toggle'),
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/com-like/$',CommentLikeToggle.as_view(), name='com-like-toggle'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my problem and solved it myself. The problem is :i'm using id in template tags. And id should be unique to each element. So i used class instead of id and problem fixed

```
{{comment.likes.count}}" href="{{comment.get_com_like_url}}" class="com-like">
```

And in the ajax

```
$('a.com-like').click(function(e){
```